# Is there a U.S. equivalent or version of the Plain English Campaign?

Tags: formality, language-evolution

I recently found out about the [Plain English Campaign](http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/), a UK-based movement for simplification of document language. They advocate the use of plain English in  corporate-to-consumer and state-to-citizen communications. There was a [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/sandra-fisher-martins-the-right-to-understand.html?awesm=on.ted.com_FisherM&utm_campaign=&utm_medium=on.ted.com-static&utm_source=t.co&utm_content=awesm-publisher) about it but I was not able to find any similar association in the U.S. - Can anybody help out?

Comment: Sounds like a silly idea to me. If contracts were written in plain English, than people would be able to understand them, and that would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: Hi Veronica, and welcome to EL&U.  Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, as it isn't actually a question about the usage of English so much as it's looking for an organization with a certain view on English.  Please see the FAQ for more details on what is and isn't on-topic for this site: http://english.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: The closest equivalent in the US is not usually English-specific. It's usually called *plain language* or *plain writing*. The [Center for Plain Language](http://centerforplainlanguage.org/) and [Plainlanguage.gov](http://www.plainlanguage.gov/) have information, including explanations of plain writing laws that now apply to the US federal government and some companies.

Comment: Sorry for the OT, I knew it was a bit borderline but this looked like the best place to ask! Thanks aedia for the tip.